# distributed transaction between two MS SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, transactions, msdtc

I need to make DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION between two MS SQL Server 2005, 
it drops an error that NO ACTIVE TRANSACTION IS PRESENT or smth like this.
DTCTESTER programs drops an error that transaction could not be done.
btw 135 port is open on the firewall.

Maybe anyone knows what a problem, or have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KB 954950](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954950/) looks like the problem, patch in a post SP2 hotfix